# utserver error while loading shared libraries libssl.so.0.9.8

Tags: linux-mint, openssl

I have problem in running utorrent server.
When i run the command

~$ utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/

It says utserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

When i searched for libssl i found that libssl1.0.0 and libssl0.9.8 both are installed.My machine is Running  64 bit -linux mint 14.

Any helps.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, I sym linked libssl1.0.0 and libcrypto.1.0.0 as libssl and libcrypto 0.9.8 but utorrent still wont start, it detected they are the wrong version `./utserver: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.0.9.8: version OPENSSL_0.9.8' not found (required by ./utserver)`